# KeyPress event handler does not mirror input text as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text area and a paragraph where I mirror the text entered by the user in the text area to the paragraph. Below that paragraph there is a code formatting tool that should be displayed when the user starts the current line in the text area with either four spaces or three back ticks. I use the event handler for the key press to achieve this behavior. However when I enter a character inside the text area then it won't be mirrored instantly in the paragraph until I enter another character. What should I do to my Javascript file so that it immediately gets the text and mirrors on the preview paragraph? I have tried **OnChange** but the result is the same, character doesn't get mirrored until I enter another character.

The TextArea

```
<text area onkeypress="duplicate()" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="10" id="text" ></textarea>
```

The JavaScript file

````
function duplicate() {
    //define the code block section
    let tool = document.getElementById("codeTool");
    //get the paragraph to mirror
    let para = document.getElementById("content");
    //get the text typed in the text area
    let texta = document.getElementById("text").value;
    //split the lines based on the newline character
    let lines = texta.split("\n");
    let cline = lines[lines.length - 1];
    if (cline.startsWith("```")) {
        tool.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    para.innerText = texta;

}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `onkeyup`.

`onkeydown` and `onkeypress` fire before value of textarea is updated.

````js
function duplicate() {

    //get the paragraph to mirror
    let para = document.getElementById("content");
    //get the text typed in the text area
    let texta = document.getElementById("text").value;
    //split the lines based on the newline character
    let lines = texta.split("\n");
    let cline = lines[lines.length - 1];
    if (cline.startsWith("```")) {
        tool.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    para.innerText = texta;

}
````

```html
<textarea onkeyup="duplicate()" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="10" id="text" ></textarea>

<p id="content"></p>
```

Comment: Works, let me implement it into my project. Thanks